# When Ubuntu Desktop provides the set-up option, "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", what does that mean?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

This question is fairly self-explanatory when installing Ubuntu directly onto a computer as the primary operating system. The difficulty arises when installing Ubuntu onto a VM like VirtualBox. The option and its warning could leave the user confused as to what actually would occur. The concern, of course, is in losing the underlying operation system and data. I think I know that it is okay to go ahead with this option, but Ubuntu could add in a little caveat to clear the air.

Comment: It does exactly what it says... But of course it doesn't delete your real disk :) only the virtual disk of your VM. So installing only one Linux in your VM this is the correct option for you.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that in Virtualbox, you're working an a virtual environment, one that thinks it's a PC all unto itself... and yes, the question is a little scary... but it applies to wanting to erase the virtual disk that you've created for the VM. Ubuntu doesn't know that your not installing on real hardware.